# How to make a scoreboard of how far someone has walked? (Minecraft Bedrock Edition)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a leveling up system for an add-on I'm making for Bedrock Edition and I need to make a scoreboard of how much someone has walked/ran, I can't figure out a way to do this.